# Passing optional parameters with default values to custom Play templates

Tags: templates, groovy, playframework

Is there a way to define custom templates with optional parameters?

Something like

```
%{
  try {
    _name = _name
  } catch (Exception e) {
    _name = "Guest"
  }
}%

Hello ${_name}
```

This way if the template is called with `name: "Foo"`, then it is used, if not, "Guest" is used.

I tried the above, and besides having the problem of not being reusable on the same page, I couldn't get it to work at all (template crashed or didn't compile, the catch clause did not run).

Is there a better way?

P.S. I'm using Play 1.2.4+ (latest 1.2 branch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use groovy expressions like this

```
Hello ${_name ?: "default"}
```

or you can do it the hard way using java code.
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/templates#fasttags